# Content-Disposition is null in React

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

I have this method in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that returns a PDF from a POST request.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDirectDepositDocument(DirectDepositForm directDepositForm)
{
    // .... 
    try
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={directDepositForm.Member}_directdeposit.pdf");
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path.outputPath + $"{directDepositForm.Member}_directdeposit.pdf"), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

When I test this in Postman I can see the `Content-Disposition` header:

[image]

In the front-end when I try to download the PDF with this method:

```
 fetch(url, options).then(response => {
        const filename =  response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
        response.blob().then(blob => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            a.click();
        }); 
    });
```

The content disposition header is null.

What could be going on here? Why can I see it in postman but not on the react side?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in the Program.cs I was missing `.WithExposedHeaders()` in the `Cors` policy.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(policyBuilder =>
policyBuilder.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true).WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition", "downloadfilename")));
```